# How to access resource located in merged dictionary from code

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I have a bunch of `Colors` inside a couple of `ResourceDicitonaries` like this:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                    xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=netstandard">

    <Color x:Key="Color.Background">#301536</Color>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

And I simply add both to the `App.xaml` like so:

```
<!--Colors-->
<ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Colors/Light.xaml"/>
<ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Colors/Dark.xaml"/>
```

The `ResourceDicitonary` file is simply a `.xaml` file without any bundled `.cs`, and both of the two dictionaries are set on the `App.xaml` without having to define them inside a `MergedDicionaries` group.

When trying to access the a `Color` from the code, I'm not able to find it, looks like it was not added to the resource list.

```
var color = Application.Current.Resources.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Key == "Color.Background")
    .Value as Color? ?? Color.Crimson;
```

Is there any way to access a resource like `FindResource/TryFindResource` available in WPF?

---

I also tried to access/see the contents of the `MergedDictionaries` but for some reason the merged dictionaries are always empty.

Comment: if you want to access a color from your resource dictionary it should be something like `var color = (Color)App.Current.Resources["Color.Background"];` and then work with the color variable.

Comment: That's the same as I did, but without the error checking. I was calling the Resources from the App class. No luck accessing keys from a merged dictionary.

Comment: Sorry, i didn't read that you don't have the `.cs`, i think in that case isn't possible to access the resource by code, maybe you should apply the color by hand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to another person I was able to construct this working code:

```
internal static Color TryGetColor(string key, Color fallback)
{
    Application.Current.Resources.TryGetValue(key, out var color);

    return color as Color ?? fallback;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, you want to add multiple ResourceDictionary in APP.xaml, it doesn't work.
I find one article about this issue, you can take a look:

https://nicksnettravels.builttoroam.com/post/2018/09/02/Getting-Started-with-XamarinForms-and-Resource-Dictionaries.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do something like that if you want to look up the parent hierarchy:

```cs
public static class ElementExtensions
{
    public static bool TryGetResource(this Element element, string key, [MaybeNullWhen(false)] out object value)
    {
        while (element != null)
        {
            if (element is VisualElement visualElement && visualElement.Resources.TryGetValue(key, out value))
                return true;
            if (element is Application app && app.Resources.TryGetValue(key, out value))
                return true;
            element = element.Parent;
        }

        value = null;

        return false;
    }

    public static bool TryGetResource<TResource>(
        this Element element,
        string key,
        [MaybeNullWhen(false)] out TResource resource) where TResource : class
    {
        if (element.TryGetResource(key, out object? value))
        {
            resource = value as TResource;

            return resource != null;
        }
        else
        {
            resource = default;

            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

It's inspired by the MAUI source code for [ResourcesExtensions](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/blob/main/src/Controls/src/Core/ResourcesExtensions.cs), which is internal unfortunately.