# MAUI; cannot access colors from resources in code

Tags: maui

I am trying to access colors from my colors file (under styles) in my maui application:

```
<Color x:Key="LiteGreen">#7DD2CD</Color>
    <Color x:Key="VeryLiteGreen">#a4dbda</Color>
    <Color x:Key="LiteBlue">#c3e1ed</Color>
```

If I wanna access the colors in xaml, this is how I did it and what worked for me:

```
BorderColor="{StaticResource LiteGreen}"
```

Now I tried to access the same color in code:

```
var color = this.Resources["LiteGreen"] as Color;
```

Which failes with "LiteGreen is not inside the resource dict"

[image]

I tried many different variations but to no avail.

EDIT:

my app.xaml (basic).

```
<Application xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Skillbased"
             x:Class="Skillbased.App">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Styles/Colors.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Styles/Styles.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Comment: See if `TryGetValue` does a better search: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55813499/199364.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can try the following code:

```
if (App.Current.Resources.TryGetValue("LiteGreen", out var colorvalue))
   var greencolor = (Color)colorvalue;
```

Comment: holy cow, that actually worked!

Answer (score 2):

When you are adding a Resource to your Application Level i.e. App.xaml.cs then to retrieve it you need to query the application resource not the local resource(all classes that inherit from ContentPage have their own resource).

Try something like:

```
var liteGreen = Application.Current.Resources["LiteGreen"] as Color;
```

Comment: Same error. Non of my styles are inside my app.xaml file. they all are under resources/colors.xaml.

Comment: @inno Can you add your App.xaml here if possible?

Comment: please find attached